# Issue facing in Google Email Migration API

Tags: google-email-migration

I am using Google Email Migration API to migrate mails from Yahoo mailbox to Gmail.

Using Google Email Migration API, I got the access token of a particular user and I am using the below API to migrate mail:

https://www.googleapis.com/upload/email/v2/users/somemailid@gmail.com/mail?uploadType=multipart

I am sending a Multipart request to the above API, I am receiving response as:

**Invalid multipart request with 0 mime parts.**

Please let me know how to solve this.

Comment: can you post the headers and body of your request?